# Unable to display information from fetched serialized api in react component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, serialization, redux

I am developing a web app that fetches concerts from an api based on a user search. However, since I want to add, and save, attributes from different users to those concerts, I decided that when a user clicks a link for an individual concert it a) gets saved to the database, and then b) renders the individual card component for that concert. However, the data rendered in the individual card is not the data from the external api, but data fetched from my own db, as to populate the extra attributes that my users have entered. That already has been a pain in and of itself. Now- here's the issue: For some reason whenever I try and display data from my redux state that's two levels deep, let's say like `concerts.attributes.venue`, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'venue' of undefined`. This happens for any nested properties I have. For more context, I am using hooks to fetch the data from my db in my functional concert component. I also tried turning it into a class component with lifecycle methods, but same issue. Part of of me thinks it is the asynchronous nature of fetching, with data rendering before the entire serialized data comes back? I am not sure. Anybody know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Share the code snippet for better understanding. its a bit difficult to just visualize the code by just your words.

you will get a some data as a response from the Api. You need to store that data to some variable. somewhat like this

**XHR call in JS and storing response to var x**

```
let x;
function successListener() {  
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);   //to parse the data to json format
x=data;
}

function failureListener(err) {  
  console.log('Request failed', err);  
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.onload = successListener;  
request.onerror = failureListener;  
request.open('get', 'URL', true);  
request.send();
```

then access the data you need like this:

```
x[key][subkey]
```

don't know what you are doing here

```
concerts.attributes.venue
```